# Php + mysql insert data securely

Tags: php, mysql, security

i'm worried about the security of my form. The idea is to make a form to participate in a contest in facebok. Basically just firstname, lastname, email. I've been searching through topics and there is a lot of info about security but i can't figure out what is enough security?
I know that there will always be a risk that someone finds a way to abuse the security, but i'd like to find a solution, which blocks the most of them. Also if there are obvious mistakes, please let me know.
Here is my code and all help and guidance is appreciated.

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost';
$user = '';
$password = '';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$firstErr = $lastErr = $emailErr = "";
$first = $last = $email = "";

function test_input($data)
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if (empty($_POST["first"])) {
    $firstErr = "Name is required";
    echo "<p>Firstname: $firstErr</p>";
  } else {
    $first = test_input($_POST["first"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first)) {
      $firstErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    echo "<p>Firstname: $firstErr</p>";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["last"])) {
    $lastErr = "Name is required";
    echo "<p>Lastname: $lastErr</p>";
  } else {
    $last = test_input($_POST["last"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last)) {
      $lastErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        echo "<p>Lastname: $lastErr</p>";
    }
  }


  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    echo "<p>Email: $emailErr</p>";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      echo "<p>Email: $emailErr</p>";
    }
  }

    if ($firstErr == false && $lastErr == false && $emailErr == false) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO contactstable (first,last,email)  VALUES(:first,:last,:email)";
    $statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':first'=> $first,
        ':last'=> $last,
        ':email'=> $email
    ));
          echo "<p>Thank you for participating!</p>";
    }
    else {
        echo "Fix the missing or incorrect lines.";
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `PDO`, it already implements the security measures for 1st order injection and when the queries are parametrized the 2nd order also prevented`(2nd order injection means data has been cycled through the database once before being included in a query)`.

But there is no harm if you implements validations for the inputs.

Comment: I was hoping to receive answers like this. That pretty much tells me, that for my purpose the form seems secure enough. I'll add some more validations. Thank you.

Comment: [SQL injection is SQL injection, no matter where the data comes from.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22729097/53114)