# Debugging SilverStripe prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, prepared-statement, silverstripe

Debugging DB queries with the ORM changes introduced in 3.2 became more difficult. Running `$dataList->sql()` gives you the prepared statement (in form of `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Title = ?`) which is a good start. `?showqueries` URL variable does the same.

How to get the values, or parameters, of the statement is what I'm interested in. I'm aware of https://github.com/lekoala/silverstripe-debugbar but **I'd like to know if there's a way to get them without any extensions in XDebug console** (or just by `var_dump`:ing something).

I looked quickly through the code of [silverstripe-debugbar](https://github.com/lekoala/silverstripe-debugbar) but didn't find an easily usable solution. If it is there somewhere please point me to it :)

Comment: AS informed by the pull requester... https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/pull/4582

Comment: I was *so* close to voting to close this [as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303972/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-a-prepared-statement) until I saw that pull request!