# How to view a prepared statement OR should I abandon dynamic table names?

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

I'm working on updating some PHP/MySQL reporting code someone wrote a few years back. There are over 50 SQL statements in a single PHP page. Some of them create temporary tables, all of them refer to at least one dynamic table (e.g. Report_201701), which is simple in PHP using a variable.

But as I adapt all these statements to MySQL Workbench to troubleshoot and enhance, this is causing issues because I can't view the the output of the prepared statements since I'm using variables for the dynamic table name.

I'm not familiar with dynamic SQL. Is there some way I can view/output the query results? [According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303972/how-can-i-view-the-contents-of-a-prepared-statement) it appears I can't.

A few of the statements return a single value, which I have been able to view by assigning to a variable like this:

```
set @sqlQuery = 
    Concat(
        'SELECT 1 as "A"
        into @sqlOut;'
    );
    #$opentickets = mysql_result($sqlQuery, 0);
PREPARE stmt1 from @sqlQuery;
EXECUTE stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
select @sqlOut;

# @sqlOut
-----------
1
```

But if I try it with results that return multiple columns or multiple rows I get errors like this:

```
set @sqlQuery = 
    Concat(
        'SELECT 1 as "A", 2 as "B", 3 as "C"
        into @sqlOut;'
    );
    #$opentickets = mysql_result($sqlQuery, 0);
PREPARE stmt1 from @sqlQuery;
EXECUTE stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
select @sqlOut;

Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns


set @sqlQuery = 
    Concat(
        'SELECT 1 as "A"
        UNION SELECT 2 as "A"
        UNION SELECT 3 as "A"
        into @sqlOut;'
    );
    #$opentickets = mysql_result($sqlQuery, 0);
PREPARE stmt1 from @sqlQuery;
EXECUTE stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
select @sqlOut;

Error Code: 1172. Result consisted of more than one row
```

What's my best approach? Replace the dynamic table name with a static name for now? (I'm thinking of doing that permanently since temp tables in this situation don't need to have names that indicate date.)

Comment: fyi, If you get really stuck then you can use the Mysql 'General Log' to record everything that goes to the database engine. It is really useful. As you have seen a lot of the libraries that build SQL will also tell you what they did. All this is very useful for debugging SQL stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RyanVincent. I'll have to check where to turn it on in case I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I stumbled upon the finding that MySQL Workbench DOES output prepared SELECT statements. No need to assign to a variable. Not sure if this will help someone, or if it should be deleted for stating the obvious.

```
set @sqlQuery = 
    Concat(
        'SELECT 1 as "A", 2 as "B", 3 as "C"
        UNION SELECT 10 as "A", 20 as "B", 30 as "C"
        UNION SELECT 100 as "A", 200 as "B", 300 as "C";'
    );
PREPARE stmt1 from @sqlQuery;
EXECUTE stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;
```

Returns:

```
A       B       C
'1'     '2'     '3'
'10'    '20'    '30'
'100'   '200'   '300'
```